# When to use CoreData in iPhone development

Tags: iphone, core-data

I've been looking into creating a new application for iOS and after my last few apps I've been tempted to use CoreData (for benefits including saving and automatic undo/redo).

I've been a little confused when trying to implement the data-model I've been given fr the project though, since it seems that CoreData seems very much much closer to a database than a data model.

Should I be using CoreData for an application that doesn't generally fit the 'large amount of data/records' description I would generally use an SQL style database for?

If it helps, the app I'm designing will be a sort of document editor, so there will be a number of objects I will need to represent (there might be embedded images, graphs/charts, hyperlinks etc within the document) and I need to create this model from an xml description.

Most of these 'items' need to implement a set of interfaces (the model was created for a Java product; I'm having difficulties seeing how inheritance and abstract interfaces can apply to CoreData), and every example I've found so far seems to add base elements (like an NSDate or String) to a simple model.

Does this sound like a candidate for CoreData, or is CoreData more of a tool for implementing a database in an application? (i.e a library system/staff database).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

consider CoreData as an option once you are able to properly write the majority of the code it will replace. so once you know how to properly serialize/deserialize, write undo/redo, KVO, copying, etc.

> Should I be using CoreData for an
>   application that doesn't generally fit
>   the 'large amount of data/records'
>   description I would generally use an
>   SQL style database for?

CoreData isn't restricted to large databases (at all) - it will work well with small sets, and beyond databases (binary files and documents, direct in memory use of models).

your example *could* benefit from CoreData. it depends on the amount of custom code you need - sometimes it is just easier to write the code if you're just using CD objects as an interface generator, and your app uses a lot of custom code/objects. to be honest, i've never used CoreData in a shipping app - i always found reasons to migrate models to existing code before then (assuming CoreData was also used during development/modeling stages).

it's a nice framework, but it shouldn't be viewed as a 'magic object generator' that will solve most problems. first, you need to understand he technologies/patterns you intend to replace with it. there is a limited number of ideal uses for it. if you can't write the code the objects depend on, don't bother using CoreData. iow - don't consider it as a replacement for initial effort because there are certainly times when it is a good choice and a bad choice - but you can't make an objective answer for your context if you don't (truly) understand what it is capable of.

Answer (score 2):

One of the purposes of Core Data is managing an object graph in memory.  This certainly fits your application.  It can then be persisted to disk easily.  Using a tool such as [mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/) allows you to use Core Data to manage the object life cycle, graph and persistence, but add your custom protocols on top.

In short, yes, you can use Core Data for non-database uses, with a bit of work to conform to the model.

Comment: Don is correct. You're going to get into trouble if you think of Core Data as "a tool for implementing a database in an application". It's an object persistence framework that happens to (usually) use a database as its data store. Treating it like a database will lead to design and coding decisions that you'll likely regret.

Comment: @Robot K - That's a much better explanation!